# Can an iterative replacement procedure be specified with a single s///?

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose we want to replace with `000` each instance of `1` that appears before the *first* character that is neither `0` nor `1`.

For example, if the original string is

```
"0011101TUVW0123ABC0123"
```

then the desired replacement would yield the string

```
"000000000000000TUVW0123ABC0123"
```

In Perl 5, assuming that `$_` holds the input string, then something like this will do the trick:

`'*any* constant you like!' while s/^(0*)1/${1}000/;`

This method just keeps applying the same substitution rule (`s/^(0*)1/${1}000/`) until it "converges" (i.e. ceases to change the input).

I want to know if there's a `s///` substition such that a *single* application of it achieves the same result.  (Think of the way that a *single* application of `s/1/000/g` is capable of replacing *every* occurrence of `1` with `000`.)

---

Note that a *single* application of `s/^(0*)1/${1}000/g`, the `/g` notwithstanding, will replace only the first occurrence of `1`, resulting in:

```
"000001101TUVW0123ABC0123"
```

Comment: Perl regex != PCRE. Can you please clarify which one you're looking for?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: OK, I take your word that "Perl regex != PCRE"; I have removed all mentions of "PCRE" from the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `\G` anchor that matches the start of the string or the position after the previous match:

```
echo "0011101TUVW0123ABC0123" | perl -pe 's/\G0*\K1/000/g'
```

Comment: I had forgotten about `\G`, and didn't know about `\K` until now.  Both are great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

I now realise that the OP probably requires a solution within the confines of PCRE, and the mention of Perl 5 is a red herring. However I've leaving this solution in place in case someone else arrives here with a similar question but without such limitations

---

The simplest way is to use an *executable* substitution that performs the translation on the initial sequence of 0s and 1s

Like this. The `/r` modifier (non-destructive substitution) requires at least v5.14 of Perl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.14;

my $s = "0011101TUVW0123ABC0123";

$s =~ s{^([01]+)}{ $1 =~ s/1/000/gr }e;

say $s;
```

#### output

```
000000000000000TUVW0123ABC0123
```

Comment: I was not aware or `/r`; I can see many uses for it; thanks for pointing it out.